# Unable to import psutil on M1 mac with miniforge: (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))

Tags: python, apple-m1, psutil

I'm using a miniforge environment on an M1 mac, and unable to import psutil:

`ImportError: dlopen(/Users/caspsea/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/caspsea/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/_psutil_osx.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/_psutil_osx.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file)`

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling using pip but that did not work. I'm using python 3.9, OS Monterey 12.2.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried:

`pip uninstall psutil`

followed by:

`pip install --no-binary :all: psutil`

Comment: Thanks - not sure why this worked but it did!

Comment: Thanks for the right answer. This is the only solution that worked so far. Would you be so kind to share what is causing this error?

Comment: @StanKosy, the precompiled binaries were architecture-specific rather than universal (which generally means the person publishing them made a packaging mistake to cause them to be recorded as for the wrong architecture, or wrongly described the package as architecture-independent); when you don't install from precompiled binaries but instead build from source, you get something targeting your own system's architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jude's answer.

I encountered

> ImportError: dlopen ...(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)) when I run Jupyter Lab from new MacBook.

And when trying install psutil, I got following error

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
> error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
> [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
Failed to build psutil
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

to fix that, I download xcode

- https://developer.apple.com/download/all/
- download Command Line Tools for Xcode
  and run "pip install --no-binary :all: psutil" again, then problem solved.

Comment: Hello, the problem is that you do not have a working C compiler. Run `xcode-select --install` and accept the prompt to install Apple's Command Line Tools.

Comment: (the `xcode-select --install` download is much smaller than the full XCode GUI, so the above comment is good advice).